# How can I solve this clipper circuit?

Tags: power-electronics

I have been trying to figure out some ways on how to resolve the following clipper circuit, but I got confused with the diode which is not in the same line with the resistor.

Also both difference potentials are positive. Does this mean the circuit cuts the signal only through its positive half wave?

[image]

Comment: You need to work out which diodes are conducting for which values of input voltage. There are three ranges that you need to consider.

Comment: It looks like homework so we won't do it for you but will help you along. Draw a diagram of the input and output waveforms you think this circuit might give. Post a photo.

Comment: We are not here to do your homework for you.  Show that you've thought about the problem, what you've tried, and what *specific* part you are confused by.

Comment: and i am not here to tell you what to do . You better watch something else if you find yourself unable to answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'll give you a general answer:

Usually, when encountering a circuit with 1 or more ideal diodes (as the question in Albanian is stating) you will split the behaviour of your components in different cases. The cases are selected according whether the diodes are in conductive or non-conductive polarity. This will yield 4 cases when you have 2 diodes. Usually one of those cases can be omitted from the start because it will be contradictory leaving three segments for the U-I-Diagram of the whole circuit.

You then can draw replacement circuits where you replace the diodes by shorts or open ends.

Alternatively there's the possibility to generate the U-I-diagram graphically by „adding“ the curves of all parts on either the I or U axis depending on parallel or series connection.

Having gained the complete U-I diagram it is easy to calculate the output behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

1) With the way the diodes are facing, the lowest voltage Vo can be is 20V (without load).
2) Once the Vi is over 20V, it starts influencing Vo through D1. It acts like a voltage divider with a low side voltage of 20 volts.
3) Once Vi is high enough to bring the point between the two diodes to 80V or higher, D2 forward conducts pinning the point between the two diodes to 80V since a voltage supply can sink infinite current.

Comment: i thought also that it would be between 20 and 80 . Thank you . Just wanted to ensure.

Comment: but does the 100k affects the 20 V ? If that happen according to my view there will be a swing in the signal and the signal will apromately be according to thevenin teorem so for (-120 : 20V ) V0= 100 / (100+50) * 20 = 13.4 V ?

Comment: @AltinGuberi If you're talking about when Vi=-120, you would see that at that input voltage, D1 would be reverse biased. Diode reverse biased means that it's an open circuit. That means the input side isn't even seen. In that case, all you have is 20V going through 100k ohms to the output. Since you have no load, there's no current flow, and you have 20V at the output.